# Question about CodeIgniter 4 URL structure

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm thinking of porting my site to CodeIgniter, but I have a few concerns mainly that I have hundreds of pages with the following URL structure that must be kept.
this is the structure that I need: https://mysite/my-url-link

Can CodeIgniter allow me to route this way?

thanks.

Comment: Sure, though its server rewrites which actually handle it

Comment: Even if I'm using controller? I thought you always had to call the controller

Comment: yeah you can define `$route['default_controller']` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Comment: I have this route, $routes->get('/blog/post/(:any)', 'Blog::post/$1'); How can I point it to mysite.com/blog-post-url (I have permanlink in db already)

Comment: Did you try looking at the docs? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#placeholders

Comment: @mario009 any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can archive this by enabling [`translate_uri_dashes()`](https://github.com/abdulla-nilam/CodeIgniter-3/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php#L54) in the settings. By default, it is `false`.

**Syntax**

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

> This option enables you to automatically replace dashes (‘-’) with underscores in the controller and method URI segments, thus saving you additional route entries if you need to do that

---

**Example**

Assume you have a URL `product/list` you can use as `product-list` or `product_list`.

```
$route['product-list'] = 'product/list';
```